# Django: sum annotation on relation with a limit clause

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a situation similar to the following one:

```py
class Player(models.Model):
   pass

class Item(models.Model):
   player = models.ForeignKey(Player,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='item_set')
   power = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to annotate `Player.objects.all()` with `Sum(item_set__power)`, taking into account only the top N `Item` when sorted by descending `power`. Ideally, I would like to do this with a subquery, but I don't know how to write it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution using raw queryset (it was easier to implement for me than using ORM, but it might be possible with ORM using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)):

```
N = 2
query = """
SELECT id,
   (
       SELECT SUM(power) 
         FROM (SELECT power FROM myapp_item WHERE myapp_item.player_id = players.id ORDER BY power DESC LIMIT %s)
   )
   AS power__sum
FROM myapp_player AS players GROUP BY players.id
"""
players = Player.objects.raw(query, [N])
```

**Update**

Adding annotations is not possible with `RawQueryset`, but you can use [RawSQL expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions):

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

N = 2
queryset = Player.objects.all()
query2 = """
SELECT SUM(power) 
  FROM (SELECT  power FROM myapp_item WHERE myapp_item.player_id = myapp_player.id ORDER BY power DESC LIMIT %s)
"""
queryset.annotate(power__sum=RawSQL(query2, (N,)), my_annotation1=..., my_annotation2=...)
```

Comment: Interesting. Is it still possible to add other "normal" annotations on the same QuerySet? In my case I have like two dozen of subquery-based annotation on the QuerySet.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.